# "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions" when trying to load workling plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, gemfile, workling

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.  I want to run a background process, independent of my Rails server.  I thought the workling plugin would helhp me out -- https://github.com/ascarter/workling .  However, upon adding this Gem to my Gemfile

```
gem 'workling'
```

and restarting my server, I get this error

```
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/workling-0.4.9.9/lib/workling.rb:16:in `<class:Hash>'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/workling-0.4.9.9/lib/workling.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in `require_application_and_environment!'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:77:in `console'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The last commit in `workling` repo you posted was on Jun 2008. The one [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/workling/versions/0.4.9.9) is using is from [February 2009](https://github.com/derfred/workling). Either way, R.I.P and there is no point trying to make it work with Rails 5 app :( I strongly recommend checking younger and actively maintained gems, like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or many others.